# Arduino Ethernet Shield connect to Azure IoT Hub

Tags: arduino-uno, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am new using Arduino.
I have Arduino One using a Ethernet shield and I need to send some information from the Arduino to the my Azure IoT Hub all the examples are using Wi-Fi shield.

I was reading the docs from Azure-IoT-Arduino SDK for Arduino but I could not find useful information.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino

Someone know where I can find information about this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean your device isn't in the [currently supported hardware list](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino#azureiothub---azure-iot-hub-library-for-arduino)? What's kind of your device?

Comment: I could not find information how to connect ethernet shield to Azure IoT Hub directly It seems is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Azure IoT HuB uses TLS to securely connect devices to the Azure Cloud.

The Arduino UNO is not capable of doing secure communication using TLS due to its low memory footprint.

To connect Arduino devices to the Azure cloud you need to look at their 32 bit ARM based offerings like

- [arduino mkr1000](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-mkr1000)
- [arduino zero](https://store.arduino.cc/genuino-zero)

There are [Microsoft Azure IoT SDKs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino) for  these platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use another device as a protocol gateway.  An easy way to get started would be to use node-red on Raspberry Pi